# Meteor / mongo db fieldname 'length' not valid?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Hi when trying a simple `collection.insert({ owner: Meteor.userId(), length:3 });` in Meteor it's executed by client but revoked by server (or in process, same for `collection.update`)
At the moment I renamed the field `length`to `len`and voila it works... But now I'm not in compliance with the GridFS spec saying: 'fs.files.length' (the project: collectionfs.meteor.com)

Anyone?

Comment: Do you actually need to store files? If you're just trying to insert a document you don't need to be concerned with GridFS.

Comment: Files = new Meteor.Collection("fs.files"); Files.insert({ owner: 'test', length:3 }); seems to work for me.

Comment: GridFS is just that, file chunks in dB - using their spec I hope to use some gridFS functionality server side. Wierd, Think I'll try on another install.

Comment: FWIW I'm using mongo 2.2.2 and meteor 0.5.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the iteration functions in the Underscore library, used extensively within Meteor, decide whether they are iterating over an array or an object by seeing if it has a numeric `length` property. I think the particular instance of this here is in `livedata/livedata_server.js` in the `set` function (line 515 or so): it interprets `attributes` as an array and then fails to find any of the actual attributes.

Perhaps we need to stop using _.each entirely in Meteor.

Comment: Thanks, should I add it as an issue in github?

Comment: For in is just as easy to write, would run faster? Closure is ok sometimes, eg. The set and unset is allmost identical?